# Why can't std::pair construct from function type that is passing by reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

I read from somewhere that constructor of std::pair is passing by value(before c++11) because if it's passing by reference, std::pair can't construct from reference function type. why?

```
//https://godbolt.org/z/5dMaG8E11
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void fun();

template <typename T>
void use(const T &)
{}

template <typename T, typename U>
std::pair<T, U> mp(const T & t, const U & u)
{
    return std::pair(t, u);
}

int main()
{
    use(::mp(fun, 3)); // failed
    use(std::make_pair(fun, 3)); // ok
}
```

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../include/c++/10.3.0/bits/stl_pair.h:217:11: error: data member instantiated with function type 'void ()'
      _T1 first;                 ///< The first member
          ^
<source>:18:9: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::pair<void (), int>' requested here
    use(::mp(fun, 3)); // failed
        ^
<source>:13:12: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'pair<void (*)(), [...]>' to function return type 'pair<void (), [...]>'
    return std::pair(t, u);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:18:11: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'mp<void (), int>' requested here
    use(::mp(fun, 3)); // failed
          ^
```

Comment: std::pair constructs it jolly well. It makes a pair that contains a function *pointer*. The problem in your code is that you are trying to convert it to a pair that contain a *function* (not pointer, not reference, just a function). Such a thing does not exist in C++.

Comment: Try `std::pair<std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<U>> mp(const T & t, const U & u)`. Or just use `std::make_pair` ; it applies a similar transformation